# Align botton div, on top of a unnested top div, where bottom div much have z-index:1;

Tags: css, html, alignment, z-index

I have a div at the bottom at a page. it's not bound by any other div. How would I manage to align it, a bit off center, with the main div. And place it at the top of the page, when the page has different heights and the div has to have a z-index:1;
The two divs top has to be aligned, one cannot be higher than the other.

The html

```
<body>
    <div id="Main"><div> //Css or html for this div can not be edited
    <div id="Our_hero_div"><div> //This has to be show ontop of main, but a bit off-center
</body>
```

CSS

```
#Our_hero_div{
    z-index:1; //this much remain
}
#main {
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net with the code that you have?

Comment: a demo would be most ideal --> if you do not want to provide a demo, we would need a better understanding of what you are asking and more info (code) to help you out...Truthfully, I don't fully understand what you are asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot get that `#Our-hero-div` INSIDE of the `#main` div, and if you cannot edit the CSS of the `#main` div, your options are limited. You can try to give it an absolute position and align its top with the top of the `#main` div using the css `top` property.

```
#Our-hero-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1em;   /* assumes the #main div has a margin top of 1em - just match this value to whatever the margin/padding of the #main div has on top */
}
```

You'll also need to use `left` or `right` to position horizontally (for that off-center thing you're after). This solution only works if that `#main` div is really at the top of the body. If there's other stuff that changes height above `#main`, then this falls apart.

Comment: Setting left or right of the #hero div wont work with the auto centering of the #main div. I will edit my post later today to clearify my problem

Comment: added some margin:50%; left:-300px; to get it aligned properly.